# index.php as Vite Entry Point

Tags: javascript, php, vite

I started a static project with a [Plain-HTML-Tailwind-Template](https://www.programonaut.com/how-to-create-a-website-with-html-and-tailwind-css-step-by-step/). It uses Vite for bundling with default config.

What i forgot is that i need a little bit of php so i have to rename my file from `index.html` to `index.php`. Of course vite no longer worked and i tried to change the entry point, but now i'm getting this error:

```
✓ 0 modules transformed.
[rollup-plugin-dynamic-import-variables] Unexpected token (1:0)
file: C:/dev/domain.de/index.php:1:0
```

Unfortunately i have very little experience with vite. how i can fix this?

Here are my files

vite.config.js

```
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, "index.php"),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.php"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

postcss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

package.json

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "vite": "^2.9.0"
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing suggests that there is a problem with a rollup plugin called `rollup-plugin-dynamic-import-variables`. This plugin is likely causing issues because it is expecting to work with JavaScript files, not PHP files.

One approach can be is , to ignore PHP files and only process JavaScript and CSS files. You can do this by modifying your `vite.config.js` file.

You can try following : modified code

```
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { html } from "rollup-plugin-html";

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(__dirname, "index.php"),
      },
      plugins: [html({ include: "**/*.php" })],
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ["*.js", "*.jsx", "*.ts", "*.tsx", "*.css", "*.php"],
  },
});
```

Note: I have not tested the code. just suggesting based on the code and information you provided.

Comment: nah, there is markup with tailwind in that php files. vite have to start with my index.php

Comment: modified my anser